# How to retrieve SOAP attachments within WCF service

Tags: wcf, soap

I have to develop a webservice that can be sent SOAP messages that contain attachments from an external consumer. I'm using .NET 4.5 and understand that WCF is the easiest technology to use to set up a new webservice that can support the validation of secure certificates - something else that my service is required to do.

I have found that some discussions about creating a Webservice CLIENT via WCF, that can send attachments in the calls to its service - but is it possible to support attachments at the server end with WCF?

Comment: Do you already have a specification of the details of the web service?

Comment: See http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/sending-attachments-with-wcf and https://www.google.com/search?q=wcf+attachments&oq=wcf+attachments

Comment: The consumer of the webservice is already written, it is owned by an external party and we need to write a webservice that it can talk to so that we can subscribe to messages that they publish. Unfortunately they issue their messages as a SOAP envelope with attachments at the bottom.

Comment: Too bad they don't follow standards.